# Knex js How to apply union on 2 tables which has different number of columns

Tags: knex.js, unions

I have 2 tables with diff columns as shown below

- Table - A Columns

---

Name, Age, Gender, email_id

- Table -B Columns

---

course, course_type, university

- How to convert below mentioned query in Knexjs

SELECT
NAME, EMAIL_ID, NULL AS COURSE, NULL AS UNIVERSITY
FROM TABLEA
UNION
SELECT
NULL AS NAME, NULL AS EMAILID, COURSE, UNIVERSITY
FROM TABLEB

Answer (score 1):

I tried below mentioned knex js query but getting error

- Knexjs query

myDB
.select('NAME', 'EMAIL_ID', {'NULL':'COURSE'}, {'NULL':'UNIVERSITY'})
.from('TABLEA')
.union(canonDB.select({'NULL':'NAME'},{'NULL':'EMAILID'}, COURSE',UNIVERSITY}).from('TABLEB'))

- Error :

Unknown column 'NULL' in 'field list'